# How is performance impacted when multiple queue managers are created?

Tags: ibm-mq

We have IBM MQ V7.1.0 installed and working in production. Can I create a queue manager in the production environment and perform stress testing on that. Will that impact other queue managers that are existing. Is there any way I can create separate environment from the installed IBM MQ (Not installing the MQ again).

Comment: When you say 'Production Environment' do mean on the same machine?

Comment: Yes. The same machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MQ is IO intensive, so performance mostly depends on the storage where the log and data directories of your queue managers are and on the capacity of the network interface(s) of your host.

If you configure the queue managers to have separate (both logically and phisically) storages for the data and log directories of each, and you provide enough bandwidth for the machine to handle the message load of multiple queue managers, performance impact of the queue managers on each other should be minimal.

That said, I don't think it's a good idea to do stress testing on an in use production environment, as the goal of stress testing is to find the load which "breaks" the system.

Comment: I agree - especially on the same machine, you will have an impact on the other things running on that same machine if you stress one queue manager and it's processes take up lots of CPU, memory etc.

Comment: but by separating the log and data files pointing it towards another workspace (like a remote location), in that sense only using the production network we can operate. my issue comes the fact that only one  MQ advance is available and I am not sure if we are going to purchase for more environments. In that case, is there a possibility that I might break the system? Also I have been trying to remotely redirect the log and data files into another system on my network I am facing lots of permission issues. This is with v_8.0, is it the same with v_7.0?